# Is this point estimate for mean biased?

Tags: point-estimation, law-of-large-numbers

I was wondering if this point estimate for mean: $\frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{i = 1}^{n}x_i$ is biased?

My first thought was that $\frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{i = 1}^{n}x_i \neq \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i = 1}^{n}x_i$, so then $\bar{X_n} \neq \frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{i = 1}^{n}x_i$ for large n, and so there must be a small bias.

However, I was also thinking that maybe $lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{i = 1}^{n}x_i = lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i = 1}^{n}x_i = \bar{X_n}$, so then that point estimate would be unbiased.

Any help with choosing which train of thought is correct would be very much appreciated!

Comment: As you write, it is obviously not biased because $E(\sum X_i) = n\mu$. The asymptotic property is not "unbisaedness", but "asymptotic unbiasedness", which holds for this estimator.

Answer (score 3):

You are correct in both senses. If the mean is $\mu$ then the bias of $S(x)=\frac{1}{n+1} \sum_{i=1}^n x_i$ is

$$b(x) = E (S(x)) - \mu$$
$$= E \left(\frac{1}{n+1} \sum_{i=1}^n x_i\right) - \mu$$
$$= \left(\frac{1}{n+1} \sum_{i=1}^n E(x_i)\right) - \mu$$
$$= \left(\frac{1}{n+1} \sum_{i=1}^n \mu\right) - \mu$$
$$= \frac{n}{n+1}\mu - \mu = -\frac{1}{n+1}\mu $$.

So for finite $n$ there is a bias of $-\frac{1}{n+1}\mu$ which will be small for sufficiently large $n$. Letting $n\to\infty$ it is hopefully straightforward to see that $b(x) \to 0$. This is known as *asymptotic unbiasedness*.